# Как использовать функцию usbprinterstatus в библиотеке TSCLIB.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dllimport, label-printer

Всем привет! На просторах Интернета никак не могу найти как использовать функцию usbprinterstatus библиотеки TSCLIB.dll, который поставляется вместе с принтером TSC MB240. Если у кого был опыт, подскажите какие у неё входные и выходные параметры.